# Any idea how to bring back the network without netplan cmd?

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, internet, netplan

There was a power-outage in our lab during the weekend, and when I was to recover one of the ubuntu server and have it booted, the network was not set automatically.

So as of now, Running "ifconfig ens160" command gives my this:

```
 ens160: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu1500
            inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe25:364c  prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 00:0c:29:25:36:4c  txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
            RX packets 153179 bytes 13743243 
            RX errors 0 dropped 372 overruns 0 frame 0 
            TX packets 83 bytes 8038 ....
            TX errors 0 dropped overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

And here is the network setting file I can find: **/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml**:

```
#This is the network config written by "subiquity'
network: 
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    es160:
      addresses:
      - 10.106.6.150/24
     gateway4: 10.106.6.254
     nameservers:
      addresses:
      -172.30.1.105
      -172.30.1.106
  version: 2
```

while I don't find **netplan** command anywhere on this host.

To dig in further, this server has been booted quite a few times in the past, and it never has such issue. When I login in the console this time, I have got such immediate messages:

```
/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available: 7: /usr/share/update-notifier/notify-updates-outdated: not found
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available exited with return code 127
```

So my question is how may I have the network setup first on this host ?

Thanks,

Jack

**UPDATEs**:

When I was to execute "nmcli" command, I have seen a list of interfaces that are of "unmanaged" status,  such as:

```
ens160: unmanaged 
        "VMware VMXNET3"
        ethernet (vmxnet3), ....
```

The NetworkManager.service seems to be up and running. I have got such information, when I run such cmd : **systemctl status NetworkManager.service,**

[image]

Comment: It looks like your system is configured to use Network Manager, not Netplan, for your configurations.  Does `nmcli` return anything?

Comment: sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service

Comment: Thanks for the helps. Please see my update on the main thread.

Comment: I am still stuck with the issue, and that ubuntu server can not be networked.  Any idea how to fix it ????